# Paypal IPN - Is it safe to use the default Magento url?

Tags: paypal, security

By default Magento have a route allowing IPN request on the url:
`http://www.mystore.com/paypal/ipn`

Here mainly 2 infos are processed by on the request:

1. Order ID: `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_getOrder()` this info in order to load magento order.
2. Email address: `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_verifyOrder()` just check if the email address sent  with the request match the one set in the backend for paypal ...

Looking at the code `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_verifyOrder()` check if the email address sent  with the request match the one set in the backend for paypal.

Note that the order id is the incremental order id ( so it is known to the customer ).
So once guessed the paypal email ID a malicious customer could  change the status of his order using a fake request pointing to the known url.

am I right ?
if so I think it would be a good practice at least to change the route to something different that the default one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question!

I had a look at the PayPal IPN documentation regarding the e-mail address and this can be considered safe:

> Before you can trust the contents of the message, you must first
>   verify that the message came from PayPal. To verify the message, you
>   must send back the contents in the exact order they were received and
>   precede it with the command _notify-validate.

So if someone sends a spoofed request, you will have to return it first to PayPal to verify it:

> PayPal will then send one single-word message, either VERIFIED, if the
>   message is valid, or INVALID if the messages is not valid.

These are the checks to perform after you received the VERIFIED response:

> Important: After you have authenticated an IPN message (received a
>   VERIFIED response from PayPal), you must perform these important
>   checks before you can assume that the IPN is both legitimate and has
>   not already been processed:
>
> 1. Check that the payment_status is Completed.
> 2. If the payment_status is Completed, check the txn_id against the previous PayPal transaction that you processed to ensure the IPN
>      message is not a duplicate.
> 3. Check that the receiver_email is an email address registered in your PayPal account.
> 4. Check that the price (carried in mc_gross) and the currency (carried in mc_currency) are correct for the item (carried in
>      item_name or item_number).

Once you have completed these checks, IPN authentication is complete.

Link to the documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/